# System.Web.Razor - strange issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC 4 application (which is System.Web.Razor version 2.0.0.0).

I have referenced external assembly from this application (which is referencing System.Web.Razor version 1.0.0.0).

I recieved System.Web.Razor v 1.0.0.0 from NuGet package of that assembly, and so added in a folder name "\Dependency" at root on my MVC application, and added following in  section in web.config.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="/Dependency/System.Web.Razor.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This works properly in my development environment.

But on production environment, it is giving me an error of

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version 1.0.0.0". 
The system could not find the file specified.
```

I have checked on production environment, and could see "System.Web.Razor" version 1.0.0.0 in Dependency folder, and also the web.config on production server contains the binding as I have shown above.

I remember, I sorted out this issue earlier, but its now occurring and I want to get rid of it permenantly.

Any idea of how to deal with this issue?

Thanks

Nirman

P.S. Few points to add -

1. The external assembly referencing to System.Web.Razor Version 1.0.0.0 is RazorEngine version 3.0.8
2. the builds are getting generated through MS Build

Comment: I'm a little confused by your file structure.  Are you deploying System.Web.Razor.dll in the /bin folder as well, or is this a substitute for that?  If S.W.R.dll isn't in /bin now, what happens when you manually add it to the deployment?

Comment: The /bin is already containing System.Web.Razor Version 2.0.0.0, I tried to replace it with S.W.R. 1.0.0.0 but it than gives error of missing Version 2.0.0.0 for obvious reasons..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to simultaneously reference both version 1 and version 2 of System.Web.Razor.dll in your project; they have many duplicate class and namespace names and can't be used together in this way.

However, the error you're seeing isn't useful or accurate.  I'll investigate why this error is being shown and file a bug for this.

In the meantime, have you contacted the owner of the package that references version 1?  If there's a hard-coded version dependency, that means that the package can't be used by you or other users who are creating Razor v2 applications.

Comment: I have contacted owner of this package, and also posted on discussion forum for this package over codeplex. I also looked into source code of the package, and could see its referring to v1.0.0.0 only... Not sure, if I should rebuild this package for Version2.0.0.0 from its source code myself, or if there is any solution of this multiple version problem.